# VerifyError of sub-classing while new loopj/AsyncHttpClient in Samsung Note3/Android 5.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-async-http, verifyerror

I'm encountering a problem of loopj/android-async-http while I'm upgrading the android build configuration and android-async-http to support Android 6.0.
Not sure if a problem of loopj/android-async-http, but I have not been able to find any solution yet. You're appreciated for any clue.

In build.gradle

```
dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
     compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
}
```

build configuration:

```
Android Studio 2.2 Beta 3 
compileSdkVersion 24 
buildToolsVersion '24.0.2'
minifyEnabled true
```

the code

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
```

Worked fine in many other devices except Samsung Note3/Android 5.0

The exception stacks (minified)

```
09-03 09:41:10.870 E/AndroidRuntime(26563): Process: com.bsx.myapp, PID: 26563
09-03 09:41:10.870 E/AndroidRuntime(26563): java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class a.a.a.a.i.b.k that attempts to sub-class erroneous class a.a.a.a.i.b.a (declaration of 'a.a.a.a.i.b.k' appears in /data/app/com.bsx.myapp-1/base.apk)
09-03 09:41:10.870 E/AndroidRuntime(26563):     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.<init>(SourceFile:208)
09-03 09:41:10.870 E/AndroidRuntime(26563):     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.<init>(SourceFile:177)
09-03 09:41:10.870 E/AndroidRuntime(26563):     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.<init>(SourceFile:147)
09-03 09:41:10.870 E/AndroidRuntime(26563):     at com.bsx.myapp.ad.SplashActivity.c(SourceFile:141)
09-03 09:41:10.870 E/AndroidRuntime(26563):     at com.bsx.myapp.ad.SplashActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:70)
09-03 09:41:10.870 E/AndroidRuntime(26563):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6283)
09-03 09:41:10.870 E/AndroidRuntime(26563):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
09-03 09:41:10.870 E/AndroidRuntime(26563):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2642)
09-03 09:41:10.870 E/AndroidRuntime(26563):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2754)
09-03 09:41:10.870 E/AndroidRuntime(26563):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
09-03 09:41:10.870 E/AndroidRuntime(26563):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
09-03 09:41:10.870 E/AndroidRuntime(26563):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-03 09:41:10.870 E/AndroidRuntime(26563):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
09-03 09:41:10.870 E/AndroidRuntime(26563):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5938)
09-03 09:41:10.870 E/AndroidRuntime(26563):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-03 09:41:10.870 E/AndroidRuntime(26563):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
09-03 09:41:10.870 E/AndroidRuntime(26563):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
09-03 09:41:10.870 E/AndroidRuntime(26563):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
09-03 09:41:10.870 E/AndroidRuntime(26563): Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class a.a.a.a.i.b.a because it failed compile-time verification (declaration of 'a.a.a.a.i.b.a' appears in /data/app/com.bsx.myapp-1/base.apk)
09-03 09:41:10.870 E/AndroidRuntime(26563):     ... 18 more
```

Comment: Have you use any try Catching exceptions from synchronized block in the same class file?

Comment: Finally I figured out it was because of code obfuscating with ProGuard. loopj/async-http-client depends on another 3rd library named cz.msebera.android.httpclient, which should also be kept from bing manified.

Comment: hi firebear, can I ask why this proguard doesn't cause issue in other phones? I recently came cross similar problem and I'm trying to find out the root cause. In my case, the system version is <= 4.4, so I can't get enough information from stacktrace